# ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key using google recapcha

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recaptcha

Here is the error ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key using google recapcha, angular js. I don't know why I am receiving this response when I have provided a valid key. What are the possible cause of this error?

## html

```
 <form ng-submit="submit()">
            <div
                vc-recaptcha
                theme="'light'"
                key="model.key"
                on-create="setWidgetId(widgetId)"
                on-success="setResponse(response)"
                on-expire="cbExpiration()"
            ></div>
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

## mycode

```
$scope.response = null;
    $scope.widgetId = null;

    $scope.model = {
         key: 'key is here'
    };

    $scope.setResponse = function (response) {
        console.info('Response available');

        $scope.response = response;
    };

    $scope.setWidgetId = function (widgetId) {
        console.info('Created widget ID: %s', widgetId);

        $scope.widgetId = widgetId;
    };

    $scope.cbExpiration = function () {
        console.info('Captcha expired. Resetting response object');

        vcRecaptchaService.reload($scope.widgetId);

        $scope.response = null;
    };

    $scope.submit = function () {
        var valid;

        /**
         * SERVER SIDE VALIDATION
         *
         * You need to implement your server side validation here.
         * Send the reCaptcha response to the server and use some of the server side APIs to validate it
         * See https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify
         */
        console.log('sending the captcha response to the server', $scope.response);

        if (valid) {
            console.log('Success');
        } else {
            console.log('Failed validation');

            // In case of a failed validation you need to reload the captcha
            // because each response can be checked just once
            vcRecaptchaService.reload($scope.widgetId);
        }
    };
```

Comment: is the url you added the captcha for 100% correct?

Comment: what url bro? ....

Comment: when you create a recaptcha you can specify domains (ie URLs) for it to be active for. Is your sites URL in the domain?

Comment: google reCAPTCHA   in the tepmplate interpolation  or variable will not do `key="model.key"` wont work.  Also check your domain in the  recaptcha  dashboard

Comment: what is your advice Sir ? why would it would not work?

Comment: yeah @NickParsons , yeah the domain , but also bro what if i want to test it locally? it that possible ?

Comment: yeah, you can add `localhost` as another domain if you're accessing it via `localhost` in your URL

Comment: how about if i have an example address  192.167.1.345:8000 ? how would i apply it to that address?

Comment: You can add IPs as well, so you would use `192.167.1.345` as the domain

Comment: Also bro there are two keys site key and secret key , which is the right one to use?

Comment: you need to use both to get a fully functioning recaptcha. But for displaying the recaptcha you need to use the site key as part of the `data-sitekey` attribute: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display